# How to multiprocess a function in python

Tags: python

My codes:

```
for batchList in all_List:
    result = getBatch_filter(batchList, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate)

def getBatch_filter(batchList, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate):
    result = []
    for item in batchList:
        a = corrupt_a(item, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate)
        b = corrupt_b(item, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate)
        result += a
        result += b
    return result
```

where batchList, a, b are nested lists like: `[[1,2,3],[3,4,1,4,6],[6,9,10,11]...]`
I would like to multiprocess the `for` loop in the function `getBatch_filter`. I have tried Pool, but it runs the entire file instead of the function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the Threading module.

Comment: What have you done to get started?

Comment: What a and b are is not very important, how batchList looks? also are you aware that you overwrite `result` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def heavy_func(key):
    #do some heavy computation on each key 
    output = key**2
    return key, output 

output_data ={}     #<--this dict will store the results
keys = [1,5,7,8,10] #<--compute heavy_func over all the values of keys
with Pool(processes=40) as pool:
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(heavy_func, keys):
        output_data[i[0]] = i[1]
```

So in your case you will do:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
# assuming  entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate are globals and defined here
def getBatch_filter(batchList):
    result = []
    for item in batchList:
        a = corrupt_a(item, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate)
        b = corrupt_b(item, entTotal, tripleList, neg_rate)
        result += a
        result += b
    return batchList, result


output_data ={}     #<--this dict will store the results
keys = all_List #<--compute heavy_func over all the values of keys
with Pool(processes=40) as pool:
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(getBatch_filter, keys):
        output_data[i[0]] = i[1]
```